# How to generate email alert for modsecurity rule set execution

Tags: nginx, intrusion-detection, mod-security2, websecurity

I wish to install ModSecurity for my web application. My application is on NGINX web server which is running in Ubuntu EC2 instance. I wish to know is there any way to generate email alert if some specific rule set of ModSecurity executes?

Thanks

Comment: Personally I find it easiest to use something like Splunk to monitor the web server log files and fire out email alerts when necessary. Not directly answering your question but gives food for thought...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes it's an option though but I was looking for a script or a free open source solution/services or library.